# DSM7: Secure connection to Synology NAS in LAN (no letsencrypt)

Tags: synology

I know from [this page](https://jeangalea.com/setup-ssl-synology-nas/) that there should be a way to use self-signed certificates in my LAN in order to establish encrypted connections between my computers and my local synology NAS.

In essence it says:

> It has two prerequisites:
>
> Your Diskstation must have a fixed IP address on your LAN. You must be
> able to add or assign certificates to devices you want to approve your
> SSL. If you can satisfy those conditions, proceed with the following
> steps:
>
> In DSM 6.0 -> Control Panel -> Security -> Certificate
>
> Click “Add” to start the process and choose “Create self-signed
> certificate”
>
> First you create a Certificate Authority (CA) which is the master key
> that will sign the site usable SSL.

However in my case (DSM 7.0-41890) I cannot see any options saying "create self signed certificate"

Does anybody know how to do this with DSM 7?

I don't need 100% security, I just want the communication between devices in my network to be encrypted. I don't want any malicious program in my network to be able to see passwords in clear text by just monitoring network traffic...

Comment: Ever get this worked out?

Answer (score 0):

Your Synology already has default certificate from Synology Inc. CA installed. You can enable secure https connection choosing port in 'Login Portal' > DSM > DSM port (HTTPS) and checking *automatically redirect HTTP connection to HTTPS for DSM desktop*.

Then if you ignore browser warnings against self-signed certificates and allow the connection, it will be fully encrypted.

If you still want to create your own certificate chain, you can generate a root and intermediate certificate with [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com/docs/automatic-https#local-https) that you can install in Container Manager. You can import them from caddy's `pki/authorities/local` into Synology with **'Control Panel' > Certificate > Add > 'Add a new certificate' > 'Import Certificate'** filling the form with `privacy.pem` and `cert.pem`.

Self-signed certificates won't be automatically trusted if your browser is on different network then your Synology, but you can tell your browser to trust it.

Answer (score -1):

There should be a subsection called "Add a new certificate", in which you can create a new self-signed certificate. A friend told me about this, I wasnt able to check it myself, so I apologize in advance in case it does not work.

Comment: _"There **should be** a subsection called "Add a new certificate", "_ As mentioned by the OP this is no longer the case.   _"so I apologize in advance in case it does not work"_ - generally not a good idea to post unverified answers or if you must ensure you do ASAP.  Otherwise it just leads to _noise_

Answer (score -1):

I think they remove this possibility in dsm 7, it was in 6